# How to assign values to multiple graphs in a loop in iOS

Tags: ios, loops

I have a loop that creates different graphs(views)

```
     for (int i = 0; i < numberOfGraphs; i++) {

    GraphView *graph = [[GraphView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin, 30, 180, 160)];

// graph.value = value;

    [self.view addSubview:graph];

    }
```

each graph should have different values.. and those values can be updated every second.. how can I do that?

If I use a timer and call the function above, then it keeps drawing the graph..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try adding the graphs in an NSMutableArray as you go through the loop so that you have a hold of each one after they've been initialized.

If you need help updating them in real time, take a look at the GraphView.m file in Apple's [AccelerometerGraph sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AccelerometerGraph/Introduction/Intro.html)